# How to support move semantics for a class template that has a reference

Tags: c++, move-semantics

**Situation**

I'm designing a class template `logic` that supports move-semantics. `logic` has a template parameter `Visitor` and a reference member that's type is `Visitor&`. That is a library code.

Users inherits the class template `logic` and pass a custom visitor such as `my_visitor`. The custom visitor may contains movable members. For example, `my_visitor` has a member `v` that's type is `std::vector`.

**Problem**

See `test2()`. When I move my_logic, `my_visitor::v` is moved as expected. However, `logic<Visitor>::vis` refers to the moved from object. Is there any good way to refer to the moved to object?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Library code
template <typename Visitor> // Concept: Visitor should have visit() 
struct logic {
    logic(Visitor& v):vis(v) {}
    void execute() {
        vis.visit();
    }
    // Other APIs

    Visitor& vis;
    // Other member variables...
};

// User code

struct my_visitor {
    my_visitor() { v.push_back(42); }
    void visit() {
        std::cout << "expected 1, actual " << v.size() << std::endl;
    }
    std::vector<int> v;
};

// User inherits all logic's APIs 
struct my_logic : logic<my_visitor> {
    my_logic():logic<my_visitor>(mv) {}
    my_visitor mv;
};

void test1() {
    std::cout << "test1" << std::endl;
    my_logic m;
    m.execute();
}

void test2() {
    std::cout << "test2" << std::endl;
    my_logic m1;
    {
        my_logic m2(std::move(m1)); // logic::vis refers to moved from my_visitor...
        m2.execute();
    }
}


int main() {
    test1();
    test2();
}
```

Comment: You have to implement your move constructor for `my_logic` (and probably delete move assignment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `my_logic` has both a member (`mv`) and a reference to that member (`vis`) and you have to ensure that the reference is always referring to the same member. With the defaulted move constructor, the new reference `vis` still refers to the *old* member, which then gets moved from. That's why you end up at `0`:

```
 m1.mv  <-----+         m2.mv
  ↑           |
  |           |
  |           |
 m1.vis       +------   m2.vis
```

One solution is, as [Jarod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36811016/2069064) proposes, to write your own copy/move constructors/assignment operators to ensure that `m2.vis` is pointing to `m2.mv`.

However, I would suggest simply avoiding the extra reference by just using CRTP and having your base `logic` class refer directly to the derived one:

```
template <class Derived>
struct logic {
    Derived& self() { return static_cast<Derived&>(*this); }

    void execute() {
        self().visit();
    }
};

struct my_visitor : logic<my_visitor) {
    my_visitor() { v.push_back(42); }
    void visit() {
        std::cout << "expected 1, actual " << v.size() << std::endl;
    }
    std::vector<int> v;       
};
```

This way, there's only one way to refer to the data - so nothing can get out of line.

Alternatively, you could explicitly `delete` the copy/move constructors and assignment operators of `logic`. This would require you to explicitly write your own for all derived types, but would ensure that you did it correctly. For instance:

```
logic(logic&& ) = delete;

my_logic(my_logic&& rhs)
: logic(mv) // always refer to me!
, mv(std::move(rhs.mv))
{ }
```

Comment: thank you the answer. It works perfectly! I changed the concept of the `logic`'s template parameter. VisitorHolder shoud have the function `visit()` that returns a visitor that has `visit()` member function.

I updated my code as http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/SvnLl0sR4JrOwMMX . I also support move assignment without reference wrapper as http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/xPFwfOuVavxmhcpw .

Comment: I copy/pasted URL for move assignment version is wrong. The corrent one is http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/L3I5A9zWhj2QM7UN .

Answer (score 1):

Use [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) instead of a native reference:

> `std::reference_wrapper` is a class template that wraps a reference in a copyable, assignable object. It is frequently used as a mechanism to store references inside standard containers (like `std::vector`) which cannot normally hold references.
>
> Specifically, `std::reference_wrapper` is a *CopyConstructible* and *CopyAssignable* wrapper around a reference to object or reference to function of type `T`. Instances of `std::reference_wrapper` are objects (they can be copied or stored in containers) but they are implicitly convertible to `T&`, so that they can be used as arguments with the functions that take the underlying type by reference.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I replaced them. Here is the original code http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/jbp876DbGDsYg6Q1 and the replaced code http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/x1QbEaOgDHmeaxjz

How to update the reference wrapper vis?

Comment: @TakatoshiKondo: Looks like a different question to me.

Comment: my problem is how the class template `logic` supports a move-semantics with updating `vis` refer to moved to object.

Comment: I suppose not but you will need it anyway otherwise the visitor may not be assigned to.

Comment: I think that I can implement move assignment operator with native reference. It's a little tricky. See http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/L3I5A9zWhj2QM7UN line16-20

Comment: @TakatoshiKondo: There's probably UB in there. Would make a good question actually

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your own move/copy constructor

```
struct my_logic : logic<my_visitor> {
    my_logic():logic<my_visitor>(mv) {}
    my_visitor mv;

    my_logic(const my_logic& rhs) : logic<my_visitor>(mv), mv(rhs.mv) {}
    my_logic(my_logic&& rhs) : logic<my_visitor>(mv), mv(std::move(rhs.mv)) {}
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbd87004c8c222ce)

And with `reference_wrapper`, you may also implement assignment in similar way.

Comment: It seems that the move constructor for `my_logic` creates a new `logic<my_visitor>`. The class template logic has other member variables (I wrote a comment). It is line 18 in your demo. I'd like to move all member variables. I just updated you demo code as http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa6ce7e2506423eb . I added a constructor for `logic`
```logic(logic<Visitor>&& other, Visitor& v):vis(v), s(std::move(other.s)) {}``` (line 9) and calling code my_logic(my_logic&& rhs) : logic<my_visitor>(std::move(rhs), mv), mv(std::move(rhs.mv)) {} (line 49). Then it works as expected. Thank you.

Comment: I realized that I can't write move assignment operator using this way. Because it requires two parameters. It seems that I need to write a different member function for that...